# ./manage.py test doesn't serve static files?

Tags: python, django-testing, django-tests

I found the following code in one project and removing it makes tests fail:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
                            (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                             {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'viewer/templates/static')}),
                            )
```

For some reason, `./manage.py test` doesn't serve static files without this line even though it works fine on `./manage.py runserver`. Why could that be?

Comment: By default, django should only be serving static content if you start it with `runserver` if you're running in debug mode (`DEBUG=True`). Otherwise, it shouldn't enable that functionality. Because it's not a default functionality of django, it needs to be enabled when you're running `test` mode. Also note that in real production use, django does not recommend serving static content this way.

Comment: @birryree: add it as an answer, I'll accept it. Would be perfect if you provided any sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you need those lines specified for `manage.py test` is because serving static files isn't default django behavior.

If you're running the server via `manage.py runserver`, [static content is only served if `DEBUG=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

This functionality is provided to help users while in development mode, and is not recommended for use in production.

From the link above:

> **Serving the files**
>
> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.
>
> During development, if you use `django.contrib.staticfiles`, this will be done automatically by runserver when `DEBUG` is set to `True` (see `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()`).
>
> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.
>
> See [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/) for proper strategies to serve static files in production environments.